# How to upgrade to PHP 7.0 on macOS Sierra?

Tags: php, macos, terminal

I tried to update my PHP version on my mac but I am facing some issues

1. When i use cURL it freezes and it will never complete the download on the terminal:

[image]

This is the cURL command that I am running is: `curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.2`

2. I tried to download a package manually but I can't extract it or even know how to install it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695717/how-to-upgrade-php-on-macos-sierra

Answer (score 0):

You can use home-brew for installation / https://medium.com/@romaninsh/install-php-7-2-on-macos-high-sierra-with-homebrew-bdc4d1b04ea6 , I find it quite better then managing with Mac OS build in PHP

Comment: i try this method also but again it stuck when download xcode command line

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough details so I will go in blind guess here.

First judging by screenshot it is stuck on `downloading`. For how long it was frozen? Maybe you didn't wait enough.

When you downloading the source what you need to do is:

Assuming you downloaded package with name `php-7.2.6.tar.gz` from [PHP Official website](https://secure.php.net/downloads.php).

1. Execute command `tar xzf php-7.2.6.tar.gz` from command line. (assuming you are in the same directory as file). It will unpack it in directory called `php-7.2.6`.
2. Enter the directory with command `cd php-7.2.6`.
3. Enter in terminal `./configure`. It will take a while, so make sure to get some coffee.
4. After `./configure` finished, execute command `make`. This will take a while as well, so you might get a sandwich.
5. Once command finished executing the last step will be executing command `make install`. It will be quicker than others, don't worry. After that you will be able to execute `php` command.
6. **Optional** Run `make test` to make sure everything is fine.

PHP has been installed, HOORAY!

Hope that helped, have a nice day. And if I answered your question, please mark it 'Answered`.